# Append HTML to PHP String

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, class

I'm not fluent with PHP so here we go...

I have a PHP variable, `$creditRating`, that can sometimes return one value or many. The values are separated by spaces, i.e.:
`$creditRating = Poor Fair Good Excellent`

I need to break this string down, append span tags to each individual string, and add a class depending on the value, so I can customize each value with its own color using CSS. It would output something like so:

```
<span class="red">Poor</span> <span class="orange">Fair</span> <span class="blue">Good</span> <span class="green">Excellent</span>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve that with the `explode` function. Please try the following code:

```
 <?php

    $creditRating = 'Poor Fair Good Excellent';
    //convert the string into array using space as delimiter
    $array = explode(" ", $creditRating);
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        //output HTML depending on the value
        if($value=='Excellent'){
           echo '<span class="green">'.$value.'</span>';
        }
        if($value=='Poor'){
           echo '<span class="red">'.$value.'</span>';
        }
    }
 ?>
```